# FB.INIT not forcing login even with status:true      js sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My app allows users to send requests using Facebook Requests Dialogue.

I run the init as follow:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
FB.init({
    appId: '193078857407882',
    status: true,
    cookie: true,
     xfbml: false,
       });
</script>
```

From what I understand in the documentation the 'status: true' is supposed to check if the user is logged in to facebook.

However in my app when the user is not logged in it just shows the following error message:

```
An error occurred with hbg. Please try again later.
```

How can I force the application to check if the user is logged in and if not to log in?

Rails 3.0.7, Ruby 1.9.2, Js SDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check login status by calling FB.getLoginStatus

```
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
        // logged in and connected user
        } else {
            FB.login(function(res) {
                if (res.authResponse) {
                    // user logged in
                } else {
                    // user cancelled login
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks DC. That looks great. So once I check the status this code will bring up the login dialogue if I am correct?

Comment: If they are not logged in it will.

Answer (score 4):

According to the Facebook docs for [`FB.getLoginStatus`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/), if you want to receive the response from passing `status: true` to [`FB.init`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/), then you need to [`subscribe`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) to the `auth.statusChange` event:

> While you can call `FB.getLoginStatus` any time (for example, when the
>   user tries to take a social action), most social apps need to know the
>   user's status as soon as possible after the page loads. In this case,
>   rather than calling `FB.getLoginStatus` explicitly, its possible to
>   check the user's status by setting the `status: true` parameter with you
>   call `FB.init`.
>
> To receive the response of this call, you must [`subscribe`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) to the
>   `auth.statusChange event`. The response object passed by this event is
>   identical to that which would be returned by calling `FB.getLoginStatus`
>   explicitly.

So in your code you would do something like

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    alert('The status of the session is: ' + response.status);
});
```

Except you would subscribe to `auth.statusChange` instead.  Note, however, that according to the [`FB.Event.subscribe`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) docs:

> auth.statusChange() does not have a 'status' field.