# FB.Init status never returns when logged in as Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

First I subscribe to `auth.authResponseChange` and `auth.statusChange`.

My Init call looks like this:

```
FB.init({
   appId  : app_id,
   status : true,
   cookie : true,
   channelUrl : 'http://domain.com/channel.html',
   frictionlessRequests:true,
   xfbml : false
});
```

When logged in as a user it works fine.

However, when logged in as a page `auth.authResponseChange` and `auth.statusChange` are never called. I also tried setting `status: false` and calling `FB.getLoginStatus(callback_function)` but the callback function is never called.

I'm pretty sure this is a bug, but **is there a workaround**??

---

Also worth mentioning -- I get the following error in the console:

> Refused to display document because display forbidden by
>   X-Frame-Options.

I added the header `X-Frame-Options: GOFORIT` to my page but the error remains.

---

The following SO questions are related but the answers do not really help:

- [FB.INIT not forcing login even with status:true      js sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252484/fb-init-not-forcing-login-even-with-statustrue-js-sdk)
- [Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491540/refused-to-display-document-because-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options)
- [How to Detect User logged as Page, FB.getLoginStatus doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312395/how-to-detect-user-logged-as-page-fb-getloginstatus-doesnt-work)

The last link above says to call FB.login() which will automatically warn the user if they are logged in as a page. However, **calling *login()* is exactly what I'm trying to avoid doing.**

---

**Added Later**: [Facebook thinks that this bug has been fixed](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/244490742333859).

Comment: What's your use-case here? As far as I know the API doesn't work when logged in as a page, are you just trying to detect that case and work around it? I suspect the only workaround is a call to login() or showing a social plugin which has an explicit error message

Comment: "are you just trying to detect that case and work around it?" << YES. Pretty much I want to know if there's a workaround that doesn't require calling login().... this bug doesn't make my app unusable, but it adds an extra step for someone logged in as a page. I'd like to be able to warn them right off the bat. I know I could do that by  redirecting to a *getLoginUrl* URL but I'm trying to avoid that as well.... I don't like the social plugin workaround either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with `getLoginStatus` not working for users signed in as a page is a known one which  will be resolved with the push on Tuesday.

Comment: this problem is happening for me now.  it was supposedly fixed a while ago (as stated in your answer and also here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/244490742333859) BUT I'm still seeing the problem.  any chance you could check into it for me?

Comment: This will be fixed on Tuesday again.